# Two questions, 1. On express router 2.request, response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nginx

[environment]
node.js, 
express, 
react, 
nginx

[ 1st question ]
if i have reloaded the website except of root url, i got an error "cannot get /... "

[ 2nd question ]
Website is stopped and no respond, when i request to server side over 6 times by ajax. If i restart my server, i can get response from server again 5 times ...
This error is so critical for me.

My codes..!
[ client ]

```js
 
  // request to server
  fetchInfo = async () => {
  const { id } = this.props.params;
  const room = await webster.get("/api/v1/conference/"+id);

  this.setState({
   info: room
  });
 }
  
  //webster.get - ajax
  function get(url, data) {
 const get = $.ajax({
  url,
  data,
  type: "get",
  dataType: "json",
 });
 const error = get.fail(() => {
  throw new Error("Error occured in request");
 });
 const info = get.done(info => {
  return info;
 });
 return info || error;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[ backend ]

```js
//app.js

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Attach database pool for req object
app.use((req, res, next) => {
 req.db = pool;
 allowCrossDomain;
 next();
});

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type'); next();
} ;

//set route for prod
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../public/dist'+ 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../public')));
app.use('/api/v1/user', user);
app.use('/api/v1/conference', conference);

module.exports = {
 app
};



//api/conference/index.js
const router = require('express').Router();
const _get = require('./get');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
 _get.searchConferenceRoom(req, res);
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
 _get.getRoomInfo(req, res); //request query to db
});

module.exports = router;



//www.js - exec file
const { app } = require('../app');
const port = require('../settings.json').http.port;
const httpServer = require('http').Server(app);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || port);

//set port
httpServer.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
 console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding your first question

> if i have reloaded the website except of root url, i got an error "cannot get /... "

this is expected since when you navigate through the router links then Javascript runs and manipulates the URL in the address bar, without causing a page refresh, which in turn does  a page transition

the **solution** is to do a "catch-all" route

just set up a catch-all on the server that sends all request to the index index.html

something like this

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../../client/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

but make sure to do this **route after your rest api**

regarding the second question it quite unclear and if i want to take a guess i think the handler of the request get stuck and does not respond to the client until you end it

Comment: i found my wrong codes finally! Those are in method "getRoomInfo".